# Bash: Regular Expressions in substitution

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing

I have a bash script to substitute number values inside a text pattern. Suppose I have a file like this:

```
word5word
word55word
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
word125word
word125word
```

I have this script to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

re='([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])'
while read line
  do
    new_line=${line/"word"$re"word"/"word"125"word"}
    echo "$new_line"
  done < /home/tomak/test.txt
```

For some reason, the 're' expression is not interpretted correctly and it prints the original lines. I just can't figure out why. It works for a singe digit, i.e. `re='[0-9]'`.

To formulate the expression, I used information from the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html#sect_04_01_03) which states that:

> Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator "|"; the
>   resulting regular expression matches any string matching either
>   subexpression.

But it just doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Note that I tried to set `shopt -s extglob` and formulate the expression like `[0-9][0-9]?` but that didn't work either.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 and have the stock bash version 4.3.30. I run the script with `bash foo.sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter expansion's substitution doesn't work with regular expressions. `extglob` can help you here, but it doesn't work with regular expressions, either.

The correct syntax for the expression under `extglob` is

```
re='+([0-9])'
```

i.e. a digit one or more times.

Test:

```
re='+([0-9])'
echo $'word5word\nword55word' | while read line ; do
    new_line=${line/"word"$re"word"/"word"125"word"}
    echo "$new_line"
done
```

Output:

```
word125word
word125word
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just substituting in patterns, I suggest sed or perl instead of bash:

```
sed -e 's/word[0-9]\+word/word125word/g' /home/tomak/test.txt
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/word\d+word/word125waord/g' /home/tomak/test.txt
```